# Get the scriptPubKey from a Taproot address

Tags: address, taproot, bech32-address, p2tr, bip350-bech32m

I have this function that converts a Bitcoin private key as an integer to a public key and an address.

```
def get_seg_v1_from_pkey(imported_key):
    imported_key_toint = int(imported_key)
    privKeytoHex = imported_key_toint.to_bytes(32, 'big').hex()
    prv = HDKey(privKeytoHex)
    prv_tnet = TNetHDKey(privKeytoHex)
    pubkey = prv.public_hex
    pub_tnet = prv_tnet.public_hex
    version = 0x01
    address = program_to_witness(version, pubkey[2:], main=True)
    address_testnet = pubkeyhash_to_addr_bech32(pubkeyhash=pub_tnet[2:], prefix='tb', witver=1, separator='1', checksum_xor=0x2bc830a3)
    return pubkey, address, address_testnet
```

HDKey imports the integer into a proper private key object like what is used in https://github.com/bitcoinops/taproot-workshop. TNetHDKey is a custom function I wrote that does the same thing as HDKey but it stores the private key in a way that makes it easily convertible to a testnet address.

I want to get the scriptPubKey from an address like in this function in https://github.com/bitcoinops/taproot-workshop:

```
def create_spending_transaction(self, txid, version=1, nSequence=0):
    """Construct a CTransaction object that spends the first ouput from txid."""
    # Construct transaction
    spending_tx = CTransaction()

    # Populate the transaction version
    spending_tx.nVersion = version

    # Populate the locktime
    spending_tx.nLockTime = 0

    # Populate the transaction inputs
    outpoint = COutPoint(int(txid, 16), 0)
    spending_tx_in = CTxIn(outpoint=outpoint, nSequence=nSequence)
    spending_tx.vin = [spending_tx_in]

    # Generate new Bitcoin Core wallet address
    dest_addr = self.nodes[0].getnewaddress(address_type="bech32")
    scriptpubkey = bytes.fromhex(self.nodes[0].getaddressinfo(dest_addr)['scriptPubKey'])

    # Complete output which returns 0.5 BTC to Bitcoin Core wallet
    amount_sat = int(0.5 * 100_000_000)
    dest_output = CTxOut(nValue=amount_sat, scriptPubKey=scriptpubkey)
    spending_tx.vout = [dest_output]

    return spending_tx
```

Notice these lines in the above function:

```
# Generate new Bitcoin Core wallet address
dest_addr = self.nodes[0].getnewaddress(address_type="bech32")
scriptpubkey = bytes.fromhex(self.nodes[0].getaddressinfo(dest_addr)['scriptPubKey'])
```

`self.nodes[0]` refers to a running instance of bitcoind on your computer. I want to replicate this function without requiring a running instance of bitcoind. In my version of this function I plan on passing in `dest_addr` because I won't have a bitcoind instance to generate it. Is there a way to get a scriptPubKey from a raw segwit v1 address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the reference Python implementation of bech32 / bech32m](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/blob/master/ref/python/segwit_addr.py). Decode the address using [`bech32_decode`](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/blob/7a7d7ab158db7078a333384e0e918c90dbc42917/ref/python/segwit_addr.py#L73-L89) and get the human readable part, data encoded (the scriptPubKey you are looking for), and whether this address is bech32 or bech32m.

Answer (score 1):

The scriptpubkey for a P2WPKH address is `0x0014{20-byte-key-hash}` (from [bip141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#p2wpkh))

You get the keyhash by decoding the address from the bech32 encoding.

You can use [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools/blob/dbdced863bd2622f4cb41595df1ecad399760d78/cryptotools/BTC/address.py#L175C1-L176) library (I am the author) to do that or to construct the spending output.

```python
>>> from cryptotools import Address

>>> addr = Address('bc1qh2egksgfejqpktc3kkdtuqqrukrpzzp9lr0phn')
>>> addr.type()
<ADDRESS.P2WPKH: 'P2WPKH'>

>>> output = addr._receive(50_000_000)
>>> output.script.hex()
'0014bab28b4109cc801b2f11b59abe0003e586110825'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my address is a segwit_v1 (bech32m). Will cryptotools work with that? And would the answer need to be modified in that case?

Comment: Oops sorry I missed that, no taproot support yet.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying